# C/C++ Serialize Fast : Boost vs Cpickle vs Json vs Protocol buffer

Tags: c++, c, serialization

I need to serialize C/C++ structure in a binary string,very fast.

Env = Windows,Boost 1.44,Python 2.4.

We have 3 structures differents to serialize:
Basic : int,double,long,float,string (or char*)
Vector: 
      - Each element can be : Basic or Vector or a Map
       --> vector< Basic,Vector,Map >
Map:
     - Each Value element can be : Basic or Vector or a Map
      --> map Basic or List or Map >

I try with cPickle to serialize structures CPython define as above.
Time to serialize  : 1,5 s
I try the same thing with boost 1.44 with different class:
    - with polymorphisme (pointer) and virtual function -> 35 s
    - with boost::variant --> 7s

I can't explain how the difference between Boost en Cpickle is too big.
I note, the serialize time of boost to serialize an vector and vector is a factor 10. ( TimeSerialize  (vector) = 10 * TimeSerialize(vector) 
So my idea, was to use boost::variant to avoid pointer. But is slow.

I didn't try protocole Buffer and JsonCpp.
I try to developp all in C++ and not use Python.
But for the moment Python is 5 faster than C++ to serialize.

If someone can help me.

Comment: Have you enabled compiler optimization (e.g. -O2) and disabled debugging (e.g. no -g)?

Comment: If Python is faster: use Python!

Answer (score 1):

Boost's design goals don't include being the fastest. I would guess protobuf would be faster but it's harder to use. I just did serialization code for my own project. I did something similar to what was implemented in [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bz744w8%28VS.80%29.aspx). It's reasonably speedy without a lot of overhead. If you really need speed roll your own like [this](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=310409).

Comment: I didn t implement my own serializer but it seem the best way.

Comment: If someone could help me for this.